# Saving myo data in background and processing it on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storage, myo

Is it possible to collect data, when application is in the background mode and store it in iphone's memory, for example: `NSUserDefaults`?

I have

- connected my app to myo device
- checked "*Uses Bluetooth LE accessories*" and
- used  `TLMHub.shared().shouldNotifyInBackground = true`

What will be the best way to store raw emg, accelerometer, gyroscope data from myo?

Comment: Never worked with this device but by your core question I suggest you to use coredata to store your data in iOS

Comment: I have read, that i have about 10 seconds to save new data, will it be enough?

Comment: I would say 10 seconds is an eternity. But try to evaluate the amount of data before going to final solution

Comment: It will be a lot of data, because it comes from accelerometer, gyroscope and emg

Comment: A lot of data or a streaming like ? You have also the possibility to create your own file

Comment: Data will appear with every move of the user, so it will be really quickly